# How to use push notification in qt web Assembly

Tags: qt, webassembly

I am beginner in web assenbly and I want to use of push notification in qt web assenbly.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Qt for WebAssembly, just setup the notification library as you would on any other web app (e.g. [Firebase Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)), then of course you can send the notifications/data to the Qt app via emscripten bindings.